# Replace comma with dot when getting floatvalue of NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, floating-point

I want the users to be able to input values above 0 for a money amount in my application. So 0,0 or any representation of zero will be unacceptable but 0,1 will be accepted, for example.

In order to do this, I was planning to get the float value of NSString and compare it to 0.0 but this does not work since our decimal numbers need to be seperated with comma, always (due to a business requirement). If the commas were dots, then the comparison does the job.

What's the most decent way to replace commas with dots in my amount texts?

PS: The user is limited to enter only numbers and just one comma, for the decimal part. 
And actually I was wondering if this is sthg that could be done with number formatters or so...

Thx in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could just use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

```
NSString *newString = [ammount stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];
```

Comment: This won't work in some countries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system  
(Eastern Arabic numerals)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [NSString+JavaAPI](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/541) category, and then do:

```
NSString* newString = [myString replace: @"," withString: @"."];
```

Of course, this may not help if the user happens to enter something like `1,000,00`.

Comment: The user is limited to enter only numbers and a comma, I will add this to my question now :)

Comment: +0: While this works, installing this category for the mere wrapping of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` with a shorter method name is more work than you gain, IMHO.

Comment: @DarkDust - Fair enough.  I just cringe every time I have to type `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` just to demonstrate a simple string replacement.  But you're right, the category only makes sense if you're going to be doing a lot of string processing operations.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a neat way to use `NSScanner`:

```
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner localizedScannerWithString:theInputString];
    float result;
    [scanner scanFloat:&result];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommend to use an NSScanner.
this is the code I use :

```
NSScanner *scanner;
NSLocale *local =[NSLocale currentLocale ];
[scanner setLocale:local];
float result;
scanner = [NSScanner localizedScannerWithString:<YOUR NSString>];
[scanner scanFloat:&result];
```

Comment: I hope that isn't the code you use. You didn't set `scanner` to anything, and fetching the current locale is superfluous, anyway, if you're using `localizedScannerWithString:`. I also recommend using `double` instead of `float` to avoid losing precision.

Comment: yes your right ... i missed something the day I shared this code ;) thanks